# pkg update doesn't get meta.txz from pkg.freebsd.org

Tags: freebsd

when I using pkg update (insall/upgradet), it show a error that timed out when downloading meta.txz. But I can download this file directly using wget.

freebsd version: 10.3-RELEASE-p19

```
[XD] % sudo pkg update           
Updating FreeBSD repository catalogue...
pkg: Repository FreeBSD load error: access repo file(/var/db/pkg/repo-FreeBSD.sqlite) failed: No such file or directory
pkg: http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/FreeBSD:10:amd64/quarterly/meta.txz: Operation timed out
repository FreeBSD has no meta file, using default settings
pkg: http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/FreeBSD:10:amd64/quarterly/packagesite.txz: Operation timed out
Unable to update repository FreeBSD
Error updating repositories!
```

Answer (score 0):

[Try this out](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/operation-timed-out.51501/)! you need to change `fetch_retry` or `fetch_timeout` in `/usr/local/etc/pkg.conf`.